# yii2 gridview multiple select dropdown filter

Tags: php, yii2

I need to explain my problem clearly
I have status dropdown in my application, am trying to have multi select dropdown filter.

**_search.php**

```
<?php
                $status = ArrayHelper::map(Status::find()->all(),'id','status');
                echo $form->field($model, 'status')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                            'data' => $status,
                            'language' => 'en',
                            'options' => [
                            'placeholder' => 'Select Status..',
                            'multiple' => true
                            ],
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true
                            ],
                    ]);
            ?>
```

**modelSearch.php**

```
if($this->status != null)
        {
            $query->andFilterWhere( "status IN (".implode(',',$this->status).")" );
        }
```

The above are my code, while am hitting search button am getting error as

**PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException**

**Array to string conversion**

Help me to sort out this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your **modelSearch.php**

```
if($this->status != null)
        {
            $query->andFilterWhere([ 'in','status',$this->status]);
        }
```

Comment: is $this->status is getting as an array?